# Slow Redis Performance with Python Redis

Tags: python, redis

I have been playing around with Redis and used the following script and the latest Redis Docker container on my test server (Intel Atom x5-Z8350 CPU with 2 GB Ram) to get an understanding of how Redis operates.

The performance I'm getting is rather disappointing. It takes 0.2169 seconds to write the data to Redis and a similar time to retrieve it again from Redis.

Is there anything I'm missing?

dataset is a Python dictionary with 725 key value pairs that look like this:

```
200001103829: {'team_1': 'Krasnodar', 'team_2': 'PAOK ', 'event_date': '2020-09-22T19:00:00Z', '1': 2.08, '2': 3.55, 'X': 3.25, 'last_update': '2020-09-22T01:30:10.666030'}
```

Script:

```
import redis
import pdb
import generate_data

dataset = generate_data.generate()

client = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)

t1 = time.perf_counter()

with client.pipeline() as pipe:
    for match in dataset:
        pipe.hmset(match, dataset[match])

    pipe.execute()

t2 = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Writing Data to Redis: {t2 - t1}')
```

Results from redis-benchmark:

```
====== PING_INLINE ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.84 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
15.10% <= 2 milliseconds
96.40% <= 3 milliseconds
98.07% <= 4 milliseconds
98.97% <= 5 milliseconds
99.43% <= 6 milliseconds
99.70% <= 7 milliseconds
99.83% <= 8 milliseconds
99.89% <= 9 milliseconds
99.96% <= 10 milliseconds
99.97% <= 11 milliseconds
99.98% <= 12 milliseconds
99.99% <= 13 milliseconds
99.99% <= 14 milliseconds
99.99% <= 15 milliseconds
100.00% <= 16 milliseconds
100.00% <= 17 milliseconds
100.00% <= 18 milliseconds
100.00% <= 20 milliseconds
100.00% <= 21 milliseconds
100.00% <= 23 milliseconds
12756.73 requests per second

====== PING_BULK ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.82 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.01% <= 1 milliseconds
16.82% <= 2 milliseconds
96.31% <= 3 milliseconds
98.12% <= 4 milliseconds
98.99% <= 5 milliseconds
99.49% <= 6 milliseconds
99.75% <= 7 milliseconds
99.86% <= 8 milliseconds
99.92% <= 9 milliseconds
99.94% <= 10 milliseconds
99.96% <= 11 milliseconds
99.96% <= 12 milliseconds
99.97% <= 13 milliseconds
99.99% <= 14 milliseconds
99.99% <= 15 milliseconds
100.00% <= 16 milliseconds
100.00% <= 18 milliseconds
100.00% <= 20 milliseconds
100.00% <= 24 milliseconds
12795.91 requests per second

====== SET ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.86 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.01% <= 1 milliseconds
12.59% <= 2 milliseconds
96.04% <= 3 milliseconds
97.90% <= 4 milliseconds
98.98% <= 5 milliseconds
99.41% <= 6 milliseconds
99.63% <= 7 milliseconds
99.76% <= 8 milliseconds
99.83% <= 9 milliseconds
99.90% <= 10 milliseconds
99.95% <= 11 milliseconds
99.97% <= 12 milliseconds
99.99% <= 13 milliseconds
99.99% <= 14 milliseconds
99.99% <= 15 milliseconds
100.00% <= 18 milliseconds
100.00% <= 19 milliseconds
100.00% <= 20 milliseconds
100.00% <= 22 milliseconds
12729.12 requests per second

====== GET ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.84 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.01% <= 1 milliseconds
13.68% <= 2 milliseconds
97.06% <= 3 milliseconds
98.51% <= 4 milliseconds
99.24% <= 5 milliseconds
99.60% <= 6 milliseconds
99.77% <= 7 milliseconds
99.87% <= 8 milliseconds
99.92% <= 9 milliseconds
99.93% <= 10 milliseconds
99.94% <= 11 milliseconds
99.96% <= 12 milliseconds
99.98% <= 13 milliseconds
99.99% <= 14 milliseconds
99.99% <= 15 milliseconds
100.00% <= 17 milliseconds
100.00% <= 21 milliseconds
12761.61 requests per second

====== INCR ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.79 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
19.32% <= 2 milliseconds
96.44% <= 3 milliseconds
98.01% <= 4 milliseconds
98.89% <= 5 milliseconds
99.50% <= 6 milliseconds
99.72% <= 7 milliseconds
99.82% <= 8 milliseconds
99.90% <= 9 milliseconds
99.94% <= 10 milliseconds
99.96% <= 11 milliseconds
99.97% <= 12 milliseconds
99.98% <= 13 milliseconds
99.99% <= 14 milliseconds
99.99% <= 15 milliseconds
99.99% <= 16 milliseconds
99.99% <= 17 milliseconds
99.99% <= 18 milliseconds
100.00% <= 20 milliseconds
100.00% <= 22 milliseconds
100.00% <= 24 milliseconds
100.00% <= 25 milliseconds
100.00% <= 27 milliseconds
12833.68 requests per second

====== LPUSH ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.79 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
16.23% <= 2 milliseconds
96.39% <= 3 milliseconds
98.13% <= 4 milliseconds
99.03% <= 5 milliseconds
99.47% <= 6 milliseconds
99.75% <= 7 milliseconds
99.85% <= 8 milliseconds
99.91% <= 9 milliseconds
99.95% <= 10 milliseconds
99.96% <= 11 milliseconds
99.97% <= 12 milliseconds
99.97% <= 13 milliseconds
99.98% <= 14 milliseconds
99.98% <= 15 milliseconds
99.99% <= 16 milliseconds
99.99% <= 17 milliseconds
99.99% <= 18 milliseconds
100.00% <= 19 milliseconds
100.00% <= 19 milliseconds
12838.62 requests per second

====== RPUSH ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.76 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.01% <= 1 milliseconds
17.63% <= 2 milliseconds
96.63% <= 3 milliseconds
98.29% <= 4 milliseconds
99.16% <= 5 milliseconds
99.57% <= 6 milliseconds
99.75% <= 7 milliseconds
99.86% <= 8 milliseconds
99.90% <= 9 milliseconds
99.93% <= 10 milliseconds
99.96% <= 11 milliseconds
99.97% <= 12 milliseconds
99.98% <= 13 milliseconds
99.99% <= 14 milliseconds
99.99% <= 15 milliseconds
100.00% <= 16 milliseconds
100.00% <= 20 milliseconds
100.00% <= 22 milliseconds
100.00% <= 23 milliseconds
100.00% <= 24 milliseconds
12894.91 requests per second

====== LPOP ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.78 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
12.86% <= 2 milliseconds
97.09% <= 3 milliseconds
98.55% <= 4 milliseconds
99.31% <= 5 milliseconds
99.64% <= 6 milliseconds
99.79% <= 7 milliseconds
99.87% <= 8 milliseconds
99.92% <= 9 milliseconds
99.95% <= 10 milliseconds
99.97% <= 11 milliseconds
99.98% <= 12 milliseconds
99.98% <= 13 milliseconds
99.99% <= 14 milliseconds
100.00% <= 15 milliseconds
100.00% <= 16 milliseconds
100.00% <= 17 milliseconds
100.00% <= 26 milliseconds
12846.87 requests per second

====== RPOP ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.83 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
13.81% <= 2 milliseconds
96.78% <= 3 milliseconds
98.32% <= 4 milliseconds
99.12% <= 5 milliseconds
99.54% <= 6 milliseconds
99.82% <= 7 milliseconds
99.90% <= 8 milliseconds
99.96% <= 9 milliseconds
99.98% <= 10 milliseconds
99.99% <= 11 milliseconds
99.99% <= 12 milliseconds
100.00% <= 14 milliseconds
100.00% <= 15 milliseconds
100.00% <= 16 milliseconds
100.00% <= 26 milliseconds
12777.92 requests per second

====== SADD ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.79 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
16.47% <= 2 milliseconds
96.15% <= 3 milliseconds
98.14% <= 4 milliseconds
99.15% <= 5 milliseconds
99.51% <= 6 milliseconds
99.76% <= 7 milliseconds
99.86% <= 8 milliseconds
99.93% <= 9 milliseconds
99.96% <= 10 milliseconds
99.97% <= 11 milliseconds
99.98% <= 12 milliseconds
99.99% <= 13 milliseconds
99.99% <= 14 milliseconds
99.99% <= 15 milliseconds
100.00% <= 16 milliseconds
100.00% <= 17 milliseconds
100.00% <= 17 milliseconds
12840.27 requests per second

====== HSET ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.82 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.01% <= 1 milliseconds
14.70% <= 2 milliseconds
96.24% <= 3 milliseconds
97.99% <= 4 milliseconds
98.83% <= 5 milliseconds
99.33% <= 6 milliseconds
99.65% <= 7 milliseconds
99.78% <= 8 milliseconds
99.89% <= 9 milliseconds
99.93% <= 10 milliseconds
99.94% <= 11 milliseconds
99.97% <= 12 milliseconds
99.97% <= 13 milliseconds
99.98% <= 14 milliseconds
99.98% <= 15 milliseconds
99.99% <= 16 milliseconds
99.99% <= 17 milliseconds
100.00% <= 18 milliseconds
100.00% <= 19 milliseconds
100.00% <= 21 milliseconds
100.00% <= 22 milliseconds
12794.27 requests per second

====== SPOP ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.83 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.01% <= 1 milliseconds
16.37% <= 2 milliseconds
95.70% <= 3 milliseconds
97.88% <= 4 milliseconds
98.92% <= 5 milliseconds
99.39% <= 6 milliseconds
99.62% <= 7 milliseconds
99.76% <= 8 milliseconds
99.82% <= 9 milliseconds
99.88% <= 10 milliseconds
99.90% <= 11 milliseconds
99.91% <= 12 milliseconds
99.92% <= 13 milliseconds
99.95% <= 14 milliseconds
99.97% <= 15 milliseconds
99.99% <= 16 milliseconds
100.00% <= 19 milliseconds
100.00% <= 20 milliseconds
100.00% <= 22 milliseconds
100.00% <= 32 milliseconds
12773.02 requests per second

====== LPUSH (needed to benchmark LRANGE) ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.78 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
15.13% <= 2 milliseconds
97.44% <= 3 milliseconds
98.70% <= 4 milliseconds
99.34% <= 5 milliseconds
99.65% <= 6 milliseconds
99.76% <= 7 milliseconds
99.83% <= 8 milliseconds
99.90% <= 9 milliseconds
99.95% <= 10 milliseconds
99.97% <= 11 milliseconds
99.99% <= 12 milliseconds
99.99% <= 13 milliseconds
100.00% <= 14 milliseconds
100.00% <= 15 milliseconds
100.00% <= 16 milliseconds
12861.74 requests per second

====== LRANGE_100 (first 100 elements) ======
  100000 requests completed in 11.71 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
0.02% <= 2 milliseconds
29.03% <= 3 milliseconds
97.18% <= 4 milliseconds
98.34% <= 5 milliseconds
98.88% <= 6 milliseconds
99.29% <= 7 milliseconds
99.55% <= 8 milliseconds
99.71% <= 9 milliseconds
99.87% <= 10 milliseconds
99.93% <= 11 milliseconds
99.96% <= 12 milliseconds
99.96% <= 13 milliseconds
99.98% <= 14 milliseconds
99.99% <= 15 milliseconds
100.00% <= 16 milliseconds
100.00% <= 18 milliseconds
100.00% <= 19 milliseconds
8538.98 requests per second

====== LRANGE_300 (first 300 elements) ======
  100000 requests completed in 23.85 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
0.00% <= 2 milliseconds
0.01% <= 3 milliseconds
0.02% <= 4 milliseconds
0.10% <= 5 milliseconds
47.06% <= 6 milliseconds
98.51% <= 7 milliseconds
99.08% <= 8 milliseconds
99.29% <= 9 milliseconds
99.44% <= 10 milliseconds
99.56% <= 11 milliseconds
99.64% <= 12 milliseconds
99.72% <= 13 milliseconds
99.78% <= 14 milliseconds
99.82% <= 15 milliseconds
99.86% <= 16 milliseconds
99.88% <= 17 milliseconds
99.91% <= 18 milliseconds
99.94% <= 19 milliseconds
99.96% <= 20 milliseconds
99.98% <= 21 milliseconds
99.99% <= 22 milliseconds
100.00% <= 22 milliseconds
4193.22 requests per second

====== LRANGE_500 (first 450 elements) ======
  100000 requests completed in 33.17 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 3 milliseconds
0.00% <= 4 milliseconds
0.02% <= 5 milliseconds
0.05% <= 6 milliseconds
0.20% <= 7 milliseconds
14.98% <= 8 milliseconds
96.22% <= 9 milliseconds
99.05% <= 10 milliseconds
99.36% <= 11 milliseconds
99.50% <= 12 milliseconds
99.58% <= 13 milliseconds
99.64% <= 14 milliseconds
99.70% <= 15 milliseconds
99.74% <= 16 milliseconds
99.80% <= 17 milliseconds
99.83% <= 18 milliseconds
99.85% <= 19 milliseconds
99.87% <= 20 milliseconds
99.89% <= 21 milliseconds
99.91% <= 22 milliseconds
99.92% <= 23 milliseconds
99.94% <= 24 milliseconds
99.95% <= 25 milliseconds
99.96% <= 26 milliseconds
99.97% <= 27 milliseconds
99.98% <= 28 milliseconds
99.99% <= 29 milliseconds
99.99% <= 30 milliseconds
100.00% <= 31 milliseconds
100.00% <= 32 milliseconds
100.00% <= 32 milliseconds
3014.95 requests per second

====== LRANGE_600 (first 600 elements) ======
  100000 requests completed in 43.56 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 4 milliseconds
0.00% <= 5 milliseconds
0.01% <= 6 milliseconds
0.03% <= 7 milliseconds
0.08% <= 8 milliseconds
1.19% <= 9 milliseconds
19.68% <= 10 milliseconds
53.16% <= 11 milliseconds
85.00% <= 12 milliseconds
98.26% <= 13 milliseconds
99.44% <= 14 milliseconds
99.62% <= 15 milliseconds
99.71% <= 16 milliseconds
99.78% <= 17 milliseconds
99.86% <= 18 milliseconds
99.90% <= 19 milliseconds
99.92% <= 20 milliseconds
99.94% <= 21 milliseconds
99.96% <= 22 milliseconds
99.97% <= 23 milliseconds
99.98% <= 24 milliseconds
99.98% <= 25 milliseconds
99.99% <= 26 milliseconds
100.00% <= 27 milliseconds
100.00% <= 28 milliseconds
100.00% <= 30 milliseconds
2295.53 requests per second

====== MSET (10 keys) ======
  100000 requests completed in 7.85 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
8.73% <= 2 milliseconds
96.44% <= 3 milliseconds
98.37% <= 4 milliseconds
99.17% <= 5 milliseconds
99.57% <= 6 milliseconds
99.77% <= 7 milliseconds
99.88% <= 8 milliseconds
99.92% <= 9 milliseconds
99.95% <= 10 milliseconds
99.96% <= 11 milliseconds
99.98% <= 12 milliseconds
99.99% <= 13 milliseconds
99.99% <= 14 milliseconds
100.00% <= 16 milliseconds
100.00% <= 17 milliseconds
100.00% <= 18 milliseconds
100.00% <= 19 milliseconds
100.00% <= 20 milliseconds
12737.23 requests per second
```

Comment: Where does the Python script execute? On same container, or totally different hosts?

Comment: Same Linux machine, but outside of the Docker container.

Comment: Installing redis-server via apt-get instead of using the Docker container has improved benchmark results, but the execution time of the script is still slow.

Comment: I have tried the code on multiple setups now. When I setup a virtual Linux machine on my main computer, the same code executes in < 50 milliseconds, whereas it needs up to 350 milliseconds on the test server and another, very similar setup. I assume it could have something to do with the single-threaded nature of Redis in combination with low end cpus, although none of the cores are saturated on my low end machines during the writing process, according to htop. I'm still looking for suggestions.

Comment: did you check your memory usage? You could be swapping to disk since you only have 2GB total memory.

Comment: I did. There was always more than enough free memory.

Comment: beware that using  decode_responses=True. will cause serious performance degradation in production. As a side effect you avoid having to deal with the binary to string conversion.

Comment: Does that affect the writing speed as well or just reading?